# Modify section (adding a vertical line to the left)

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{IndianRed3}\bfseries\scshape\filleft\lsstyle}{}{2em}{#1\quad\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}}
\begin{document} 
    \section{A section}
example for a very \tiny{tiny} \normalsize \LaTeX \ document 

    \section{Another one}
example for a very \tiny{tiny} \normalsize \LaTeX \ document 
\end{document}
```

How should I change the following command

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{IndianRed3}\bfseries\scshape\filleft\lsstyle}{}{2em}{#1\quad\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}
```

so that the line appears to the left and the section title is left aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution. However note the default Computer Modern (or Latin Modern) has no small caps in the sans font. Also, I removed the spacing between section label and section title since you display no section label (was it intentional?).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
%
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\sffamily\color{IndianRed3}\bfseries\scshape\filright\lsstyle}{}{0em}{\rule[-0.25cm]{1.5pt}{1cm}\quad#1}

\begin{document}

    \section{A section}
example for a very \tiny{tiny} \normalsize \LaTeX \ document

    \section{Another one}
example for a very \tiny{tiny} \normalsize \LaTeX \ document

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But the code?

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I forgot post. It will be fixed within seconds!

Comment: No problem:-)! thanks for this nice solution.